# How to cut a stitched leather belt without it unraveling?

Tags: clothing, leather

I am talking about the belts with stitches along its edges. I read that if I cut it to shorten it at the buckle end, the threads will come loose. What do I do to prevent this?

The following is a picture of the belt:

[image: Belt stitching]

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the belt - but having an idea of what it might look like - here's an idea that might work:

I assume the buckle end of the belt is pulled through the lower part of the buckle and folded back onto itself and sewn across the edge to hold it in place.

1. To remove the buckle, carefully cut that stitching open and pull the belt through to the length you want and trim it so that the new edge hits the back of the belt at about the same place as before.
2. Sew across to hold the belt in place.
3. The cut threads along the edge of the belt will now be on the underneath side of the belt.  If you don't fix them in place, they will unravel and eventually show on the outside of the belt. You can use Fray Check (fabric glue found in craft or fabric stores) or superglue to glue the cut threads to the underside of the belt so they won't unravel.

**You can also take the belt to a shoe repair place** to resew the cut edge, unless you have an awl (sharp hole-maker) to make new holes in the new belt edge that you can hand-sew through to fix the folded-over part to the back of the belt.  Then glue the cut thread as above.

**If the sewn edge of your belt is a thin leather** ("boondoggle") and not thread, you can try gluing the cut stitches, but you can also have a shoe repair place sew them down when they sew across the new edge.

Good luck!  Good for you for trying to fix the belt you like instead of just tossing it.

Comment: its actually screwed on, making it easier to detach from the buckle. The only problem are the seams. To glue the threads at the end can i use lactite glue instead since thats what i have?

Comment: heres an image of the belt: http://i.imgur.com/UXuFHo1.jpg   and is it okay to use an normal scissors to cut the leather belt?

Comment: Is this the glue? https://www.amazon.com/Loctite-Ultra-Control-4-Gram-1363589/dp/B003Y49R7G  the description says it works on leather so I think it's fine (that it will work).  I don't see why you can't use scissors if they work for you.  Good news about the screw - that is easier than sewing.  Good Luck!

Comment: its Loctite Liquid Professional Super Glue 20-Gram Bottle (1365882) which also says works on leather. The screw makes it easier i got it as a gift.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason shortening the belt on the other end is not possible, right?  so ..

just dab a spot of super glue into the holes the sitching makes in the leather for a centimeter or so back from where you are going to cut through the sitching. On both sides of the belt. Make the cut. The thread will be held in place by the glue

The “you must be crazy” version of the answer is .. start unsitching the thread at the buckle end until you are 2 centimetres (1 inch) back from the cut line, tie a new, colour matched thread to the old thread, on the inner side of the belt, pulling the knot tight at the hole the thread comes through. Option to apply a dab of superglue to hold the knot. Cut the leather to shorten. Now thread a needle on and resew the decorative border using the existing holes. Finish the stitching normally and voila!